# How do I get all the value of Input fields (including select, text-area) from multiple fieldsets inside a single form element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I've a form, which consists both plain `<input>` tags as well as other fileds inside `<fieldset>` .

When I do `$('.form-class-name').serialize();` , it only takes the value of the those input fields which are outside of the `<fieldset>` . However if I put some value to the input field inside `<fieldset>` , serialize will take the value of them too.

The problem here is that, I need all the values of input fields in the whole `<form>` element even if they are blank, which in my case jquery serialize isn't doing.

Any help/reference/suggestion would be great.

Here's a sample of my html. https://jsfiddle.net/7h61bboc/6/

Has anyone been through this road? Help me.

Here's the updated html with desired result and current result : https://jsfiddle.net/gqwg4pd5/2/

**Note: I was trying to get even the blank values of Radio, Checkbox, Select, which is  not supported by Jquery Serialize.**

Comment: [`id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id) of element in `document` should unique

Comment: @guest271314, the will I be able to get all the values? Let me check that.

Comment: _"Let me check that."_ Does removing duplicate `id` from `document` return expected result?

Comment: No, it didn't work out as expected, I'm with the same result.

Comment: Can you include text of expected result , updated `html` with duplicate `id`s removed at Question?

Comment: Ok, I can, but you meant to remove the duplicate id in radio, select button etcs right?

Comment: Yes. Have you reviewed link at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38966515/how-do-i-get-all-the-value-of-input-fields-including-select-text-area-from-mu?noredirect=1#comment65287497_38966515? What is expected text result of `.serialize()`? Can you include updated `html` at jsfiddle or Question?

Comment: Here's the updated one: https://jsfiddle.net/gqwg4pd5/1/

Comment: No values are assigned at two closing groups of `<input type="hidden" name="_previous" value="">
         <input type="hidden" name="_next" value="">` elements at https://jsfiddle.net/gqwg4pd5/1/? why is value `_previous=1&_next=&923%5B%5D=&_previous=2&_next=` expected to be returned from `.serialize()`?

Comment: I need all the fields name, so that when I save them to database, I could have a blank value set for the blank field. 
There is no problem with that previous and next, it can be a multipage form, thus it's like that.

Comment: Why is `1` expected to be `value` of `_previous`, where `_previous` `value` is set to empty string `""` at `html`?

Comment: Ah! sorry, because I'd clicked the previous button,  to show you the expected result, and I forgot to empty that. But their expected value is blank in case user leaves the field blank. Hope you got me.

Comment: _"But their expected value is blank in case user leaves the field blank. Hope you got me."_ Not certain what you mean? How does user input text at `hidden` `input` element? If `value` at `input type="hidden"` element is set to empty string `""` at `html`, the result at `.serialize()` would be empty string `_previous=` ?

Comment: If user click the previous page/Next page, this will update the value of _previous and _next value. That's it, it has nothing to do with anything else.

The previous comment couldn't be edited. Sorry

Comment: _"If user click the previous page/Next page, this will update the value of _previous and _next value. That's it, it has nothing to do with anything else."_ Description of requirement does not appear at Question? Are you trying to set `<input type="hidden">` element value when sibling `<button>` element is clicked?

Comment: No, they are already there, I'm adding those hidden input element dynamically. It's a multipage form, thus there are mutiple _next, _previous values in the serialized values.

Comment: _"No, they are already there"_ Can you update `html`, reproduce issue at jsfiddle?

Comment: here you go https://jsfiddle.net/gqwg4pd5/4/

Comment: The `hidden` `input` elements at `html` have empty string set at `value`? Also `.form dynamic-progress-form` is not a valid selector.

Comment: Yes they are supposed to be empty, why the selector isn't valid? that's the class of the form element. Was that where I was being wrong all the way?

Comment: _"why the selector isn't valid?"_ `dynamic-progress-form`, if referencing a `className`, is missing `.`, e.g., `.form .dynamic-progress-for‌​m`. Though, note, `.dynamic-progress-form` is not a child element of `.form`, but `.form` element itself. The selector should be `.form.dynamic-progress-form`. _"Was that where I was being wrong all the way?"_  ,  _"Yes they are supposed to be empty"_  `.serialize()` and `.each()` appear to be returning correct result. Not certain why expected result is a value at `<input type="hidden">` element, where value is set to empty string at `html`?

Comment: Hi, Everything was fine, but the problem itself was that I wanted to retrieve blank values of radio, check boxes, and every other input elements. I think, I forgot to mention that in the question, I was trying to get even the blank values. However that's not quite supported by Serialize itself. Thus had to seek other way around.

Comment: _"Hi, Everything was fine, but the problem itself was that I wanted to retrieve blank values of radio, check boxes, and every other input elements. I think, I forgot to mention that in the question"_ Yes, `.serialize()` returned expected result given empty string as `value`. _"Thus had to seek other way around."_ Have you resolved Question?

Comment: Yes, I resolved the question, Serialize doesn't retrieve the blank value of radio, checkbox and select.

Answer (score 3):

```
        var values = {};
          $.each($('#myForm').serializeArray(), function(i, field) {
              values[field.name] = field.value;
                 });
```

try this below code

```
                $('#myForm').bind('submit', function () {
                    var elements = this.elements;
                 });
```

Comment: It appears that the new HTML 5 form inputs don't work with serialize Array in j Query version 1.3. This works in version 1.4+

Comment: I'm doing the same, but it's not working in my case, I've a jquery version of v1.11.3 .
Is this because of jquery old version?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myForm').submit(function() {
// get all the inputs into an array.
var $inputs = $('#myForm :input');

// not sure if you wanted this, but I thought I'd add it.
// get an associative array of just the values.
var values = {};
$inputs.each(function() {
    values[this.name] = $(this).val();
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks but as I denoted in the original question, serialize() isn't taking all the fields value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a serialize() function of JQuery:

```
var datastring = $(".form-class-name").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "your url.php",
        data: datastring,
        success: function(data) {
             alert('Data send');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks but as I denoted in the original question, serialize() isn't taking all the fields value.